# How create a cube with a rippled surface

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

I'd like to create a cube with one side rippled in the form of a sine wave.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. I wrote a Python function to create a sine wave curve
2. I extruded the curve to form a 2d sine wave
3. I boolean joined the 2d sine wave to a 3d cube

This results in a 2D sine wave on top of a 3d cube - picture attached.

Instead, I'd like to have a solid 3d object with one side being a wave. Ideally, I'd like to have an object with no internal faces, as I am exporting this into another program that does not deal well with internal faces.

[image: Sine wave Cube]

Answer (score 5):

You can just extrude your sine surface second time, and then

scale it to 0 in extrude direction <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>(<kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>), <kbd>0</kbd>

[image]

In my gif I also recalculate normals at the end.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do, but I can't seem to replicate what you're doing. I took my curve, made it 2D, converted to a mesh, then extruded in the z direction. However, when I scale how you describe, the entire 3D curve becomes smaller or larger in amplitude, the bottom surface doesn't flatten out like yours does. Could you explain the scaling step a little more? Thanks...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Actually, it looks like it is working now. By selecting the vertices on the bottom surface I was able to replicate what you did. Previously I had selected all the vertices when scaling.